# Rails 3 Active Record and client_side_validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am looking to understand what is going on with the following

I have a message model

```
 class Message 
 include ActiveModel::Validations
 include ActiveModel::Conversion
 extend ActiveModel::Naming
```

I would like to use validates_uniqueness_of :email through the gem client_side_validations, however the gem seems to rely on using

```
< ActiveRecord::Base
```

so my model should look like so

```
class Message  < ActiveRecord::Base
 include ActiveModel::Validations
 include ActiveModel::Conversion
 extend ActiveModel::Naming
```

however if I include the inheritance I get an error message along the lines of

```
undefined method []
```

Something is not right and i was wondering if anyone could explain why this is happening

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if it is related to the error, but you should not be including/extending all those `ActiveModel` modules if you are inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base`, since they will be included through inheritance.

Comment: Thanks, Im guessing that's the answer then, will try it out later, do you want to put that as the answer?

Comment: Ok, posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it is related to the error, but you should not be including/extending all those `ActiveModel` modules if you are inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base`, since they will be included through inheritance. I would first try taking those out and see if that works.